# How to fix Microsoft Graph FetchError write EPROTO decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a system that uses Microsoft Graph to get bookings of resource mailboxes from outlook with the option to checkin and checkout.
Now for some reason my system started to fail this saturday and when I checked the logs I get weird errors:

```
Unhandled error for request GET api/Company/id/rooms/example@company.com/bookings: FetchError: request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/example@company.com/calendar/calendarView?$orderby=start/dateTime%20asc&$top=1000&startDateTime=2023-03-06T00:00:00.000Z&endDateTime=2023-03-06T23:59:59.999Z failed, reason: write EPROTO C00777E6B87F0000:error:0A000119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:610:
```

The other reason I also get is `reason: read ECONNRESET`

I have had this system running for a long time and never got such errors before, so I don't know what's happening and I can't seem to find the errors either.

Any ideas why these errors are occuring?

Thanks in advance!

Billy Cottrell

## Update:

It seems like the issue is no longer occurring even though nothing has been changed, not in the app/API or portal and neither inside Azure AD.

I am assuming that the issue is from Microsoft Graph their side exclusively, and since the issue is no longer occurring they probably have fixed the issue on their side.

Not only that but I still have no idea why it was happening in the first place or what caused it, but I'm glad it got solved after getting 3 thousand errors in 2 weeks on only 6 devices (there are many more devices not yet being monitored at the moment, so It's probably around 11k errors).

I'm hoping that Microsoft will give an explanation of this issue like why it occurred and what can be done to prevent this issue in the future. Especially since the amount of devices that will send requests will increase drastically.

## Status information:

- First Seen: 4 March 2023 12:45 AM UTC
- Last Seen: 17 March 2023 7:46 AM UTC
- Total Amount of devices monitored: 6 actual devices (4 test devices)
- Total Amount of devices: 25 (with test devices: 32 in total)
- Total Amount of known errors: 3043 (probably around 20% of the actual amount of errors)
- OS:

  - 90% Android 9
  - 9% Android 8.1.0
  - <1% Android 8.0.0

Comment: If your app registration is using a certificate (?) then maybe it has expired? Does your app registration use certificate as a secret?

Comment: @Nikolay I only have a client secret in azure ad, and it only expires in 2099 so I doubt that's going to be an issue here